# Copying to /system - android

Tags: android, root, su

I am been trying to copy a apk from assets of another apk to /system.

Here is what I have done,it was working in my previous app but not in this.I have added permission for wrtiting external storage.
It is successfully copying to internal storage,not not to /system.
Is there any way to directly copy to /system?

> copyStream("y.apk","/sdcard/x.apk");
>
> ```
> Process mSuProcess;
>
> mSuProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
>
> new DataOutputStream(mSuProcess.getOutputStream()).writeBytes("mount -o remount rw /system");
>
> DataOutputStream mSuDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mSuProcess.getOutputStream());
>
> mSuDataOutputStream.writeBytes("cp /sdcard/x.apk /system/app/x.apk"); 
>
> mSuDataOutputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
> ```

Comment: Did you forget the newlines on your other commands?

Comment: Thank you,it solved.Any way to directly copy it to /system?

Comment: Not without some invocation of `su`, unfortunately.

Comment: Does `cp y.apk /system/app/x.apk` not work?

Comment: Well,actually y.apk is in asset folder of an app,so by using copyStream,it will be copied to sdcard,then using cp to /system,.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. Sorry, then you will have to copy the file somewhere since the assets folder is not on disk anywhere (it is in the compressed application file).